# Excel - Multiplying daily values for each week

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

[image: Here's how my table layout looks]

What I have: over 200 rows, each with three values, each for a unique day. Only values for workdays are listed, so sometimes there may be days or even whole weeks missing from the list because of holidays.

What I need: for every **finished** week that had **at least one daily row** (and therefore the day was present on the list) I need to multiply the values from the column DIF (The formula looks like =(1-ValueDayOne)*(1-ValueDayTwo)-1) and then create a list of those weekly values.

Could anyone help me with that? If anything I wrote is not 100% clear feel free to ask questions, I tried to specify all the required information but I may have accidentally omitted something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula to copy to "WEEKDIF" column is:

`=PRODUCT(IF(($A$2:$A$21>=A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3))*($A$2:$A$21<A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3)+7),(1+$B$2:$B$21),1))-1`

This is an array formula, so you need to finish it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

How it works:

- `A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3)` and `A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3)+7)` calculates date of Monday actual (week of date in current row) and next weeks.
- `($A$2:$A$21>=A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3))*($A$2:$A$21<A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3)+7)` - checks whether a row is withing actual week.
- `=IF(...,(1+$B$2:$B$21),1))-1` returns `1+diff` for actual week and `1` for all others (need to multiply with 1 if we don't want to change result).
- `=PRODUCT(IF(...)-1` - calculates product of all numbers and subtract 1 as per original formula.

Note: to be consistent within calculation I've changed `1-dif` to `1+dif`, if my assumption isn't correct, you can change it back.

[image]